# Can't draw a line in the g element of a CustomSVGSeries in react-vis and clojurescript

Tags: svg, clojurescript, react-vis

In the following working code:

```
[:> rvis/CustomSVGSeries {:data [{:x x :y y 
                          :customComponent (fn []
                             (r/as-element [:g {:className "etiqueta"}
                                                [:text
                                                  [:tspan {:x 0 :y 0} "Hidrógeno "]
                                                  [:tspan {:x 0 :y "1em"} "Alfa"]]]))}]}]
```

I'm trying to add a `line` element:

```
[:> rvis/CustomSVGSeries {:data [{:x x :y y 
                          :customComponent (fn []
                             (r/as-element [:g {:className "etiqueta"}
                                                [:line {:x1 0 :y1 0 :x2 600 :y2 600 :strokeWidth 5 :fill "red"}]
                                                [:text
                                                  [:tspan {:x 0 :y 0} "Hidrógeno "]
                                                  [:tspan {:x 0 :y "1em"} "Alfa"]]]))}]}]
```

But doesn't work.

For me it's even stranger that some other SVG elements work; for instance `[:circle {:cx 0 :cy 0 :r 20 :fill "orange"}]` and `[:ellipse {:cx 0 :cy 10 :rx 61 :ry 30 :fill "yellow"}]` work perfectly...

I also tried with `[:polyline {:points [0 0 600 600]}]` but did not have luck either...

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Also isn't that `:stroke` instead of `:fill`?

Comment: @cfrick Ouch! It was as esay as you say! I ommited `:stroke`... ¡my bad! :) I'm editing the post in case someone else falls in my mistake... ¡Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cfrick comment, I changed `:fill` with `:stroke` and it worked fine, both for `:line` and `:polyline`.